# Creating a Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

My question is to find a basis for $S$ when $S = \{ \langle a,b,c,d \rangle \mid a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} , a=c, d=a+b \} $. I'm struggling creating a set of vectors that is linearly independent with the given stipulations. I've tried everything that I could think of, and just need to know where to start. Is there a common characteristic of linearly independent vectors?

Answer (score 1):

$$\{ \langle 1,0,1,1 \rangle, \langle 0,1,0,1 \rangle \}$$

If we freely choose $a$ and $b$, we can let $a=1$ and $b=0$ or else we can let $a=0$ and $b=1$, but those choices force us to assign certain values to $c$ and $d$.  If you can identify some variables that you're free to choose, then let one of them be $1$ and the rest $0$, and do that for every choice of the one that is to be equal to $1$, that will do it.  This should also suggest why the term "degrees of freedom" is sometimes used.

Comment: I'm a little confused because these are not linearly independent (I checked with Gauss-Jordan).

Comment: Typo: the second one should have had $d=1$.  But either way they are certainly linearly independent. There must be some error in your process of checking it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ah. I see my error. Thanks.